# 403 error with Flyer Saucer when creating pdf from html Spring Boot ressources

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, flying-saucer

I want to generate a pdf from html, with Spring Boot, so I use **Flying Saucer**, and generate the pdf with ITextRenderer

But in my html the resources cannot be loaded. When I call :

```
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    iTextRenderer.createPDF(os);
```

I get this error :

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://my-custom-url.com

It works on my localhost, but not when deploying to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

My server rejected the requests due to a missing user-agent in Flying Saucer library.

To fix it, I overloaded the ITextUserAgent, to add manually a user-agent :

```
public class ResourceLoaderUserAgent extends ITextUserAgent
{
    ResourceLoaderUserAgent(ITextOutputDevice outputDevice)
    {
        super(outputDevice);
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream openStream(String uri) throws IOException
    {
        URLConnection connection = new URL(uri).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
        connection.connect();
        return connection.getInputStream();
    }
}
```

And I used it like this :

```
    ITextRenderer iTextRenderer = new ITextRenderer();

    ResourceLoaderUserAgent callback = new ResourceLoaderUserAgent(iTextRenderer.getOutputDevice());
    callback.setSharedContext(iTextRenderer.getSharedContext());
    iTextRenderer.getSharedContext().setUserAgentCallback(callback);
```